# iOS - How to properly reload a cell before inserting it dynamically in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been facing an understandable behavior while dynamically inserting an object in my `datasource`.

Here is my code :

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

[_dataSource insertObject:newObject atIndex:indexPath.row];
[_collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
```

What I am doing here is inserting an object in my `datasource` (because this object wasn't ready at launch, and I receive it in a `delegate` method).

Then, I want to trigger my `cellForRow` at this specific indexPath in order to create and insert the appropriate cell.

The issue here is that it briefly display the **previous** *content* of the cell.

Even though I got this in my custom `UICollectionViewCell` class :

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.mediaContainer = nil
    self.outletTitle.text = ""
    self.outletImage.image = nil
    self.outletButtonAction = nil
    self.bottomView = nil
}
```

Am I using `prepareForReuse` in a wrong way ?

Should I call `reloadItemsAtIndexPath` before inserting it ?

Here is my cellForRow :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Object *object = [_datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = nil;

    switch (object.type.intValue) {

        case CELLTYPE1...  :
        // specific cases for specific cell type

        .
        .
        .
        case CELLTYPE2:
        {
            static BOOL nibMyCellloaded = NO;
                if (!nibMyCellloaded) {
                    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
                    [self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseId"];
                }

                CustomCollectionViewCell* customCell = (CustomCollectionViewCell*)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                [customCell updateCellOutletWith:_customView vc:self];
                 cell = customCell;
            break;



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: use `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cell, for: indexPath)` at `cellForItemAt` and use `reloadItemsAtIndexPath`

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside `prepareForReuse`. Also, try to add a new item using `performBatchUpdates`.

Comment: I think you should first insert the item in the array than reloadItemsAtIndexPath. Later handle the content to display or handle celldeque issue having a check on cellforrow.

Comment: Show your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set outlets to `nil` in `prepareForReuse()` because the cell isn't loaded from Storyboard or NIB again. Just reset your contents (e.g. texts, images, control values). You can use the following rule of thumb: Reset only the values in `prepareForReuse()` which you set in `cellForRow()`.

When your outlets are set to `nil` then `cellForRow()` can't assign new values to the views, and thus you will see old values.

Comment: No, you're setting `mediaContainer` and `bottomView`to `nil`.